# Which collection do you recommend?

Tags: c#

I need to store values like in dictionary.

For example

```
public class Dictionary
{
}
```

Dictionary is main topic.

And want to keep there in values with keys.

```
First Key | Second Key | Value
----------+------------+------
  En      | Name       | Shop    
  En      | Path       | /en  
  De      | Name       | Geschäft  
  De      | Path       | /de
```

Code:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary();
var enPath = dictionary.En.Path;
```

So what am I supposed to use to achieve something like above, is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<String,String>, String> d = new Dictionary<Tuple<String, String>, String>();
```

The advantage of Tuple is that it keeps track of uniqueness of the combination 2 elements well without you having to build that by implementing interfaces.

Basic example, that I don't recommend with records with more than a couple fields in it:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<String,String>, String> d = new Dictionary<Tuple<String, String>, String>();
d.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("123","456"), "abc");

Console.WriteLine(d.ContainsKey(new Tuple<String, String>("123","456"))); // returns true
Console.WriteLine(d.ContainsKey(new Tuple<String, String>("123","4567"))); // returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shoul avoid giving your classes the same name as classes that exist in .NET.

Secondly, I don't think this request you to create a new class at all. This can be achieved by using .NET's `Dictionary<>` type:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
dictionary["En"] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary["En"]["Name"] = "Shop";
dictionary["En"]["Path"] = "/en";

dictionary["De"] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary["De"]["Name"] = "Geschäft";
dictionary["De"]["Path"] = "/de";
```

You could create a class that has `Name` and `Path` properties instead of using the inner dictionary, but I wouldn't call it `Dictionary`.

Maybe something like `Shop`:

```
public class Shop
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Shop>();
dictionary["En"] = new Shop { Name = "Shop", Path = "/en" };
dictionary["De"] = new Shop { Name = "Geschäft", Path = "/de" };
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of achieving this. The first is simply having a Dictionary of Dictionaries:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<Dictionary<string,string>>();
dictionary["en"] = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dictionary["en"]["name"] = "Shop";
```

This will work, but you will have to remember to instantiate every internal dictionary before accessing it (my second line, above).

An alternative is using a Dictionary where the key is a Tuple, an ordered pair of values. If you're using C# 7.0, you can use value tuples as the key:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<(string,string), string>();
dictionary[("en", "name")] = "Shop";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a question where opinions will probably arise. But, I felt the need to tell you that your question is not bad, just wrongly formulated.

To me, this is not a *collections* problem, **but more of an OOP problem.**

Your best bet is probably to separate what you need in different classes.

Your situation seems to suppose that you would need  some kind of `Location` class that can contains a `Name` and a `Path` (which could potentially be properties).

```
public class Location
{
    public Location (string path, string name){
        Path = path;
        Name = name
    }
    public string Path{ get; private set }
    public string Name{ get; private set }
}

Location EN = new Location ("/en","Shop")
```

You could then add them to a dictionary or a list depending on what you think is the best fit.

You could get a similar syntax (`EN.Path` or `En.Name`) to what you asked with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Dictionary<Tuple<String, String>, String>
```

should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

For this you would need to use a nested Dictionary if you wanted to use Dictionaries.

It would look something like this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
dictionary.Add("En", new Dictionary<string, string>());
dictionary["En"].Add("Name", "Shop");
```

However based on the limited information and the data presented you should just use a DataTable.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("FirstKey");
dt.Columns.Add("SecondKey");
dt.Columns.Add("Value");
dt.Rows.Add(new Object() {"En", "Name", "Shop"});
```

Then you can use Linq to query the data table.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Dictionary // Use a different name than Dictionary
{
    public string FirstKey { get; set; }
    public string SecondKey { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class MainClass
{
    List<Dictionary> MyDictionary = new List<Dictionary>();

}
```